# in Twilio-node how can I verify if the error is an http 500 error?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I need handle specifically the http error 500, the documentation is clear that this errors can be handled as this

```
https://github.com/twilio/twilio-node#handle-exceptions
```

```
try {
  const message = await client.messages.create({
    body: 'Hello from Node',
    to: '+12345678901',
    from: '+12345678901',
  });
  console.log(message);
} catch (error) {
  // You can implement your fallback code here
  console. Error(error);
}
```

the problem is that I don't know what is the structure and which property I need to check in order to validate that this is a 500 error (seems that HTTP errors returns a different structure compared to API twilio errors) and try to emulate this kind of errors is a bit difficult

could you tell me what is the structure of that error or where I can find the structure? or even better if this is a custom error and includes a typescript definition could be great know how to find this...thank you

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the telnyx part here. You are using the Twilio API and the Twilio node package, right?

Comment: @IObert my mistake, I paste the wrong url, I fixed this, yes..I'm using Twilio API and twilio-node package, thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is how you handle exceptions using the [Twilio Node Helper Library](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/reference/twilio-node/):

> Handle exceptions If the Twilio API returns a 400 or a 500 level HTTP
> response, twilio-node will throw an error including relevant
> information, which you can then catch:

```
client. Messages
  .create({
    body: 'Hello from Node',
    to: '+12345678901',
    from: '+12345678901',
   })
 .then((message) => console.log(message))
 .catch((error) => {
    // You can implement your fallback code here
    console.log(error);
});
```

or with async/await:

```
try {
  const message = await client.messages.create({
     body: 'Hello from Node',
     to: '+12345678901',
     from: '+12345678901',
  });
  console.log(message);
} catch (error) {
  // You can implement your fallback code here
  console. Error(error);
}
```

The error property in the catch will include the Twilio API error. According to the [source code](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-node/blob/main/src/base/RestException.ts) you will find:

> error.status
>
> error.message
>
> error.code
>
> error.more_info
>
> error.details

The full list of error codes is found in the [Error and Warning Dictionary.](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors)

Comment: I just wanted to validate that error 500 follows the same error structure as API errors:
error.message,
error.code and error.code is 500

thanks

Comment: @clagccs, check the link to the source code and you will find the structure. The "error.code" is the Twilio returned error code from the Error and Warning Dictionary. `error.status == XXX` is how to check for a specific HTTP Status Code.